# visual studio code - changed files remain yellow after git commit

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode version 1.21.1 on a 64-bit windows 10 machine. 
I make some changes to my code, open a git console outside of the editor, and then type a commit command:

```
git add --all && git commit -m "test"
```

I notice that the changed files remain yellow despite of my commit, and only if I close and reopen the editor, the yellow color disappears. Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try only click on "refresh" on source control window instead a close/open editor?

Comment: @jahuuar You are right, thanks. It's just that I'm used to Atom where it happens automatically.